# Firefox hangs on Ajax sites. Advice?

Tags: firefox

Since a few days ago, Firefox hangs for whenever I go to AJAX script intensive sites, such as Gmail of Yahoo mail.

- The site loads fine, but when I click on, say inbox, everything freezes.
- Firefox does not respond at all for a long time (many minutes).
- No processor cycles are being used
- resetting Firefox profile, disabling add-ons, safe-mode.... nothing helps.
- Did some Windows-7 updates recently.
- It's a corporate laptop, so who knows what other updates, software are installed.
- Everything is fine through Chrome.
- Sometimes Firefox will give a "script not responding" message, but it doesn't clear the freeze if I click to stop script.
- Sometimes Gmail will give a "you might want to disable Google labs" message, but it doesn't clear the freeze.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried using firebug to see where the timeouts are coming from?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @amiregelz:   The latest, 14.0.1:   That update was recent too.

Comment: @soandos:   Well, I have just installed it, but this is probably beyond my capabilities unless you tell me what to look for

Comment: FWIW, Google Maps seems to work fine (!)